# About standard deviation expansion

Tags: biostatistics, bioinformatics

Recently, I read an academic paper. There was a formula that I could't understand.
[image]

SD represents standard deviation, n (n+1) represents the number of samples.
Does anyone know how this formula is derived?

Comment: Looks like the sample variance update in [Welford's online algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford's_Online_algorithm) (with n shifted by 1) combined with a Maclaurin-type expansion for a square root of a sum of two terms (looks like something akin to $\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt{a}(1+b/a)^\frac12$ then expand the second term using the series for $\sqrt{1+x}$. Something more or less along those lines at least)

Comment: Thanks for your help! It seems that the formula is derived using your method. But I still confuse about the final term o(1/n^2).